# jQuery `on` method is not binding event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, primefaces

I have a problem with binding (or firing) `click` event.

```
var Edocs = function() {
return {
    Utils: function() {
        var initHorizontalResizer = function() {
            console.log('Edocs.Utils.initHorizontalResizer()');
            $('.resize-main-content').on('click', function() {
                console.log('abc');
                if ($('[id="menu"]').hasClass('slidedOut'))
                {
                    $('[id="menu"]').removeClass('slidedOut');
                    $('[id="content"]').removeClass('resized');
                } else {
                    $('[id="menu"]').addClass('slidedOut');
                    $('[id="content"]').addClass('resized');
                }
            });
        };
        return {
            init: function() {
                console.log('Edocs.Utils.init()');
                initHorizontalResizer();
            }()
        };
    }()
};
}();
```

When I open javascript console I see the following values: `Edocs.Utils.init()` and `Edocs.Utils.initHorizontalResizer()`, but when I click on `.resize-main-content` element - nothing happens. So I tried to paste this binding directly to console and... - it's working! Why?

I'm using Primefaces 5.0 (jQuery 1.10.x)

Comment: The element to which you have binded click event is it dynamically generated elements on ur page ? if you dont have any idea abt it then just post your HTML DOM structure here

Comment: Yes it can be dynamically generated. it's working. Thanks

Comment: yeah then those are delegated events , you need to bind the event handler and event to a element which will be available in your page on DOM load, like `document` which  `Rory` has suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `.resize-main-content` element is dynamically appended to the page, you need to use the delegated version of `on`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.resize-main-content', function() {
    // rest of your code...
});
```

Note that `document` should be changed to select the nearest parent element of `.resize-main-content` which is available on DOM load. I just used `document` here as an example.